# Avoid commit and push comments and logs

Tags: git

Is there any config to avoid commit and push comments and logs to the repository?

for Example:

```
// This is the name of the user, and shall not commit/push to the remote origin
var name = "Behrouz"

fun doSomething() {
    println("This line shall not commit/push to the remote origin")
}
```

Comment: you can try the interactive `add`  with `git add -i` , like this you can specify which changes you actually want to have in your commit

Comment: Just an opinion : you're trying to build a personal hell for no real gain here. It will become incrementally more and more difficult to maintain as commits pile up. Complex operations (conflicts on rebase?) will become a nightmare. I *might* be overprotective from ignorance of your context, granted, but still, be **sure** you understand what it entails.

Comment: What do you expect from a person who checks out a fresh clone of the repository? Do you expect them to fill the gaps? All of them?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a pre-commit hook and with some static code analysis check if the code is "clean" enough to be committed.

Comment: I Do not wanna stop commit, just Ignore somethings

Comment: I Do not wanna stop commit, just Ignore somethings and continue